# How te set diffrent homedirectories for multiple OUs?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, home-directory

I'm building a script that checks if the homedirectory of the users are correct and if not set the correct path. OU-1 has a diffrent path than OU-2 and some users are an exception. But the script isn't working.

This is what I got so far:

```
$folderpath  = "\\172.16.32.27\gebruikers\homedir\", "\\172.16.32.27\share\homedirectories\"
$homedrive   = "H"
$SearchBase  = "OU=test,DC=Test,DC=org", "OU=users,DC=Test,DC=org"
$domain      = "test.org"
$excludes    = @("test", "user22")
$i = 0

$filter3 = "homedirectory -notlike '$("$homepath[$i]")' -and samaccountname -ne '$($excludes -join "' -and samaccountname -ne '")'"

$SearchBase | foreach { 
    Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_ -Filter $filter3 -Properties HomeDirectory, UserPrincipalName, Homedrive, samaccountname | % {
        $homedirectory = "$($folderpath[$i])$($_.SamAccountName)"

        if (!(Test-Path -Path $homedirectory)) {
            New-Item -Type Directory -Path $homedirectory

            $acl = Get-Acl -Path $homedirectory

            $permission = $_.UserPrincipalname, 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
            $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
            $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

            $permission = "$domain\Domain Admins", 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
            $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
            $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

            Set-Acl -Path $homedirectory -AclObject $acl
            Set-ADUser $_ -HomeDirectory "$homedirectory" -HomeDrive $homedrive
        } elseif ($_.HomeDirectory -ne "$homedirectory*" -or $_.Homedrive -ne "$homedrive") {
            Set-ADUser $_ -HomeDirectory "$homedirectory" -HomeDrive $homedrive
        }
    }
    $i++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a mapping between OUs and home directories:

```
$homeShares = @{
  'OU=test,DC=Test,DC=org'  = '\\172.16.32.27\gebruikers\homedir'
  'OU=users,DC=Test,DC=org' = '\\172.16.32.27\share\homedirectories'
}
```

you can process them like this:

```
foreach ($ou in $SearchBase) {
  Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou ... | ForEach-Object {
    $homedirectory = Join-Path $homeShares[$ou] $_.SamAccountName
    if (Test-Path ...) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

---

With that said, an IMHO much cleaner approach would be to put all home directories under a single share, adjust the (NTFS) permissions on that shared folder like this:

- *Administrators:*

  - Full Control (this folder, subfolders and files)
- *SYSTEM:*

  - Full Control (this folder, subfolders and files)
- *Authenticated Users:*

  - List Folder (this folder only)
  - Create Folders (this folder only)
  - Write Attributes (this folder only)
  - Write Extended Attributes (this folder only)
- *CREATOR OWNER:*

  - Full Control (subfolders and files)

and have missing home directories automatically created with a simple logon script. In batch it would look somewhat like this:

```
if not exist \\server\share\%username% mkdir \\server\share\%username%
```

but you could use VBScript or PowerShell just as well.

Enable [Access-based Enumeration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681.aspx) on top of that, and your users will not only be able to access just their own home, but also won't even see anyone else's.