# Adding ACL rule to folder overwrites all rules

Tags: powershell, permissions, automation, directory, acl

The problem I need to solve is I need to make a folder on a network share for a newly created user. This is done by System Center Orchestrator, after the user is created I need to copy a dummy folder with certain rights, add the newly created user in the ACL's and delete the workflow account from those ACL's. (the user that creates the folder gets added automaticly.)

The folder gets created succesfully and gets the same permissions as the dummy folder, now I need to add 1 ACL rule to those permissions.

Here is some sample code I'm using:

```
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read, Write" 

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain\createdUser1") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (
              $objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType
          )

$originalACL = Get-ACL "\\shares\createdUser1"
#$orignalACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($True,$False)#doesn't help either
$originalACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

Set-ACL "\\shares\createdUser1" $objACL
```

The only problem I'm having is that it doesn't add the ACL rule but it overwrites all rules that this folder currently has. How can I add 1 rule to to an existing ACL without overwriting the original rules?

source sample code: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx

EDIT1:
Using the module provided on https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/ does the same thing. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$colRights = "Read, Write"
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain\createdUser1") 
Add-NTFSAccess -Path $folderPath -Account $objUser -AccessRights $colRights
```

Comment: The code you posted has `SetAccessRulProtection()` commented, so it should not remove existing ACLs. Also, if the purpose of this is to create user home directories you may want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36405756/1630171).

Comment: It's not for home directories, just for shared folders. They get acces to it through GPO's. And that's commented out on purpose because it says on the end that even that doesn't work.

Comment: Repeating myself: since you don't use `SetAccessRulProtection()` your code does not remove existing ACLs.

Comment: Also repeating myself. Using `SetAccessRuleProtection()` doesn't help.

Comment: Nobody told you to use it anyway.

Comment: Misread your comments, i didn't know that would remove inheritance. Changed my code but all my ACL's are still getting overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your code that would remove ACLs except for the (now commented) line

```
#$orignalACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($True,$False)
```

That line will **remove** inherited ACLs, so of course it won't help.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> public void SetAccessRuleProtection(
>     bool isProtected,
>     bool preserveInheritance
> )
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> *isProtected*
>   **true** to protect the access rules associated with this ObjectSecurity object from inheritance; **false** to allow inheritance.
>
> *preserveInheritance*
>   **true** to preserve inherited access rules; **false** to remove inherited access rules. This parameter is ignored if *isProtected* is **false**.

I suspect you ran that line once before, thus removing inherited ACLs. To correct that mistake you need to re-enable inheritance first, either manually or by calling `SetAccessRuleProtection()` with the first parameter set to `$false`:

```
$orignalACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($false, $true)
```

Comment: Changed my code like you said. Uncommented that 1 line and changed it to `$originalACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$true)` but this still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked for me:

```
$colRights = "Read, Write"
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain\createdUser1") 
add-NTFSAccess -Path $folderPath -Account $objUser -AccessRights $colRights
```

We ran it from an other user account and suddenly the code worked. This was found by testing the script on local folders. Here it didn't delete any other ACL's. This will probably be something with share permissions or security permissions. (locally I'm full admin but on the shares I'm not.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Set-ACL "\\shares\createdUser1" $objACL
```

Change to this:

```
Set-ACL "\\shares\createdUser1" $originalACL
```

You had modified the `$originalACL` when you ran `$originalACL.AddAccessRule($objACE)`